# PHP - Append file in a compressed archive (tar.gz)

Tags: php, compression, addition, tar, phar

I'm doing a log archive. I use the class PharData to create an archive in .tar.gz
`$logslist` is an array that stores files to compress. Here is my code:

```
$archive = new PharData('logsArchived.tar');
foreach($logsList as $logFile)
{
    $archive->addFile($logFile, Utility::getFilenameOfPath($logFile));
    unlink($logFile);
}
$archive->compress(Phar::GZ);
unlink('logsArchived.tar');
```

My question is how I can directly add files in the compressed archive in tar.gz or retrieve the contents of the compressed archive to store it in a new archive which I create.